# MYSQL query for getting rows with one hour difference

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with this data

```
id       user_id    latitude       longitude       updated_at
1        1          13.21          102.41          2012-08-06 13:24:06 
1        1          13.31          102.52          2012-08-06 13:54:06
1        1          13.51          102.65          2012-08-06 14:24:06
1        1          13.61          102.33          2012-08-06 14:34:06
1        1          13.71          102.57          2012-08-06 15:24:06
1        1          13.81          102.90          2012-08-06 16:24:06
```

I want to retrieve all rows with one hour difference from the `last updated time`.

i.e if i search at `2012-08-06 16:24:06` i want to get only these rows

```
1        1          13.21          102.41          2012-08-06 13:24:06 
1        1          13.51          102.65          2012-08-06 14:24:06
1        1          13.71          102.57          2012-08-06 15:24:06
1        1          13.81          102.90          2012-08-06 16:24:06
```

Comment: Am asking mysql have any direct query for this?

Comment: I think if you keep the last update time you can use this time argument for your query. `$lastUpdateTimeThatIKnow="2012-08-06 16:24:06"; SELECT * FROM .... WHERE updated_at>='$lastUpdateTimeThatIKnow'`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%i%s') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%i%s');
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0778/5)

Comment: i have edited my question. retrieve all rows with one hour difference from the last updated time.

Comment: what's the exact expected output?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has functions to extract the hour, minute and second part from a given time. You can use this to compare the current second and minute to the second and minute in the field.

```
WHERE SECOND(updated_at) = SECOND(CURTIME()) AND MINUTE(updated_at) = MINUTE(CURTIME())
```

Comment: This will give only one row if updated_time will match with current time?

Comment: No it gives you all rows that have the same minute and second value, like in you sample. But use Omesh's answer, it does the same but in a more elegant way.